# Fatal Error: Uncaught Error: Call To A Member Function Query() On Null In C:\Xampp\Htdocs\Laundry-Master\_header.Php:46

Tags: php, mysql, database, xampp

I am using an existing project using XAMPP but it gives me this error:

> Undefined Variable: Pdo In C:\Xampp\Htdocs\Laundry-Master_header.Php
>   On Line 46

However when i comment out the existing database code it runs fine

_header.php

```
<?php

                          $active ='';
                          try {#displays categories existing in database
                              $sql = 'SELECT * FROM category';
                              $stmt = $pdo->query($sql);
                              $stmt->bindColumn('name', $name);
                              while ($result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOUND)) {
                                if(isset($_GET['category'])  && $_GET['category']=== $name){
                                  $active = 'active';
                                }else{
                                  $active = '';
                                }
                                  echo "<li class='{$active}'><a href='index.php?category=$name' class='ctgy_link'>$name</a></li>";
                              }
                          } catch (PDOException $e) {
                              $error = $e->getMessage();
                              $result = array();
                          }

                           ?>
```

index.php code

```
<?php require "_header.php"; ?>
```

Comment: Well, obviously `$pdo` is undefined. Little we can help here... Most likely you have not included your database connection code in that header file.

Comment: Check your path and/or file name. Error reporting will be of help here.